# Sublime 3 font size of definition hover

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to manage the font size of the function definition hover on ST3?

Here's what I see:

[image]

I've tried adding `font.size` to the theme for this element which is `popup_control html_popup` according to [docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html) but it doesn't appear to accept this.

*Update*: I found that pasting this CSS in my color theme plist addresses the list/links but not the title. I have tried to use a plugin like ScopeHunter to find the context of the 'definitions' title but it doesn't work for popups.

```
<key>popupCss</key>
<string><![CDATA[
    html {
        background-color: #404238;
        color: #F8F8F2;
    }
    a {
        color: #66D9EF;
    }
    .error, .deleted {
        color: #F92672;
    }
    .success, .inserted {
        color: #A6E22E;
    }
    .warning, .modified {
        color: #FD971F;
    }
]]></string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is look at the HTML that is used in the popup, to help decide what CSS selectors to use in the color scheme's `popupCss` to change the appearance of the popup.

In this case, the code is in `Packages/Default/symbol.py`, which you can view using https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer:

> ```
> <body id=show-definitions>
>     <h1>Definition%s:</h1>
>     <p>
>         <a href="...">...</a>
>     </p>
> </body>
> ```

So you can use the following CSS in your `popupCSS` to target it and change the color of the "Definitions" text, for example - to prove the selector is working [(the official recommendation is to use the `id` from the `body` tag)](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/minihtml.html#best_practices):

```
#show-definitions h1 {
    color: #b3bc20;
}
```

however, specifying the `font-size` seems to have no effect, at least in build 3154, so I think there is a bug in ST.

Comment: Ah thanks. I am able to change the size of the h1 by targeting the `html` tag for `popupCss`. Can't get the font weight to change however.